# Cause CMAKE to generate an error

Tags: cmake

How can I get CMAKE to generate an error on a particular condition.  That is, I want something like this:

```
if( SOME_COND )
  error( "You can't do that" )
endif()
```

Answer (score 264, accepted):

The [`message()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html) method has an optional argument for the mode, allowing `STATUS`, `WARNING`, `AUTHOR_WARNING`, `SEND_ERROR`, and `FATAL_ERROR`. `STATUS` messages go to stdout. Every other mode of message, including none, goes to stderr.

You want `SEND_ERROR` if you want to output an error, but continue processing.
You want `FATAL_ERROR` if you want to exit CMake processing.

Something like:

```
if( SOME_COND )
  message( SEND_ERROR "You can't do that" )
elseif( SOME_CRITICAL_COND )
  message( FATAL_ERROR "You can not do this at all, CMake will exit." )
endif()
```

Comment: What the heck is an `AUTHOR_WARNING`?

Comment: @AlexisWilke: the CMake docs state `AUTHOR_WARNING = CMake Warning (dev), continue processing`, suggesting that it is to be used for debugging CMake scripts. Just a wild guess.

Comment: @AlexisWilke The `AUTHOR_WARNING` indicates a warning that is not useful to the end user but to the developers. It can either remind them to fix some hack / todos or indicate warnings that should be fixed but does not affect the CMake run for the user. Thats why the user can suppress these warnings with `--Wno-dev`.

Comment: CMake now has *many* more message modes that accompany [`message()`](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/latest/command/message.html), including `VERBOSE`, `DEBUG`, and `TRACE`.