# Options for CMake commands

Tags: cmake, gfortran

The [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/cmake2.6docs.html#command%3acmake_minimum_required) for the `cmake_minimum_required` command says:

```
The FATAL_ERROR option is accepted but ignored by CMake 2.6 and higher. 
It should be specified so CMake versions 2.4 and lower fail with an error 
instead of just a warning.
```

**But**, it doesn't say what the valid options are for `FATAL_ERROR` - am I missing something blindingly obvious?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5403636/cause-cmake-to-generate-an-error

Comment: @KyleKanos Can you explain what the `FATAL_ERROR` option in `cmake_minimum_required` should be? A string? How do the arguments of `message` relate to those of `cmake_minimum_required`?

Comment: FATAL_ERROR is not _an_ option, it **is** the option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no additional arguments required for `FATAL_ERROR` in the context of `cmake_minimum_required`.

You use it like this:

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8 FATAL_ERROR)
```

or

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.11.1 FATAL_ERROR)
```

In the context of `message`, you *do* pass an additional argument:

```
message(FATAL_ERROR "My message...")
```